# uninstalling and re-installing apache/php and other services

Tags: batch-file, windows-services

I'm posting today to find out whether it is possible to install-uninstall services such as Apache from a memory stick using command prompt.

I am using xampp  for my LAMP Stack for windows.

---

**Question 1**

The reason for this, is that I travel frequently to and from various different locations. for the purpose of traveling light; my boss has requested that I take a company regulated memorystick which will be used to install/uninstall the Apache services using a pre-built batch script.

I will have access to the elevated prividgles on the computers I will be staying at. but a majority of these machines might not have the needed requirements for me to sucessfully develop.

So I was wondering if just having a folder in my tree with the exe/libraries?

---

**Question 2**

I have this batch script. The problem is, that regardless of the primary input. it automatically goes to `:Install`.. What is going wrong?

```
@ECHO OFF
@ECHO Service Management 

@echo Please Select an Option

@echo 1) Install Apache and other set services
@echo 2) Uninstall Services
SET /p option = Please Select: 

IF "%option%" == "1" GOTO Install
IF "%option%" == "2" GOTO Uninstall
IF "%option%" gtr "2" GOTO Error
:Install
SET /p path=Enter Path Of MemoryStick (letter only): 
@echo Install
PAUSE
EXIT
:Uninstall
SET /p path=Enter Path Of MemoryStick (letter only): 
@echo Uninstall
PAUSE
EXIT
:Error
@echo Error. Please Re-run
PAUSE
EXIT
```

Comment: How are you going to configure where your scripts are handled?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution. Assign your memorystick to a letter which is not usually used. Z:\ for example. Nothing will use it, unless set.

You do not need your Command prompt. You can easily copy over the necessary folders/files.. For example:

> C:\xampp\apache
>
> C:\xampp\php

over to your memory stick. Make the changes to the necessary configuration files within the Apache directory. In this case it would be:

> Z:\apache\conf\httpd.conf

Move everything which says `C:\xampp\htdocs` to a different directory on your memory  stick. For example. Say if you wanted to use the directory *WebScripts*

Take this example:

```
#
# DocumentRoot: The directory out of which you will serve your
# documents. By default, all requests are taken from this directory, but
# symbolic links and aliases may be used to point to other locations.
#
DocumentRoot "Z:/WebScripts"
```

Line 191 on a stock httpd.conf

```
<Directory "Z:/WebScripts">
    #
    # Possible values for the Options directive are "None", "All",
    # or any combination of:
    #   Indexes Includes FollowSymLinks SymLinksifOwnerMatch ExecCGI MultiViews
    #
    # Note that "MultiViews" must be named *explicitly* --- "Options All"
    # doesn't give it to you.
```

Line 221 on a stock httpd.conf

Create that directory within your Z:\ root. If this does not exist then you will encounter errors with installing the service from your memorystick.

**Installing Apache Services**
in your apache directory (Z:\Apache) you will find `apache_installservice.bat` and `apache_uninstallservice.bat`  run these with administration rights.

The services will be created and will run through the exe located at: Z:\Apache\bin\httpd.exe
which will gather all your configuration files and run an apache service with PHP Support.